# Private instance variable in a modular pattern

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = (function(){

    var _blah;

    function doStuff(){
        //how to make _blah instance specific
        //and access it here?
    }

    function bar(blah){
        _blah = blah;
        doStuff();
        //this.blah = blah?
    }

    bar.prototype.getBlah = function(){ return _blah; };

    return bar;

})();

var foos = [];

$.each([1,2,3], function(i, v){
    var f = new foo(v);
    foos.push(f);
});

//all instances of foo
//gets _blah set to 3
console.log(foos[1].getBlah());
```

I have two questions regarding the module above:

- How do I set a property that is specific for each instance? Right now you can see that `_blah` gets overwritten, which is pretty obvious. But I need some help with the syntax. My guess is that I need to set it in the constructor like the comment. Is that the right way to do it?
- How do I access the property in another method? As far as I know, `this` refers to `window` in `doStuff()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ncg2M/1/

Comment: What is `doStuff()` supposed to be ? Shouldn't it be an instance method ?

Comment: @Sniffer I use it to bind event listeners to a `new XMLHttpRequest()` which i create in the constructor method. It's the XHR that I want to be instance specific so it doesn't get overwrtitten. Does the method need to be instance specific as well?

Comment: Yes, you can make it an instance method for this purpose.

Comment: @Sniffer In other words, adding it to the prototype?

Comment: Yes, adding it to the prototype.

Comment: @Sniffer Ok, final question: Does `this` always refer to the current instance in a prototype function?

Comment: Question 2: You can create private member for example '_self=this;'. And access to your private member _self inside any function which gives you your instance foo. Because, this can refer to event instance if for example if you pass you get blah function to event.

Comment: Yes, `this` always refer to the current instance in prototype function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I set a property that is specific for each instance? Right now you can see that _blah gets overwritten, which is pretty obvious. But I need some help with the syntax. My guess is that I need to set it in the constructor like the comment. Is that the right way to do it?

Yes. That's the right way to do it, using `this.blah = // value`, but of course this makes the variable `blah` accessible publicly without any restriction.

> How do I access the property in another method? As far as I know, this refers to window in doStuff().

`doStuff()` method doesn't make a lot of sense, because when you define a function like that inside a modular, then it is usually a utility function that is used by other instance methods.

Comment: Regarding `this makes the variable blah accessible publicly without any restriction`. Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: @Johan Check Douglas Corckford's [important article](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) on the subject.